# Java и вывод в консоль из message resource

Tags: java, дата, locale

В задании указано, что информация в консоль должна выводиться из message resource (впервые столкнулся). Программа изменяет язык в соответствии с раскладкой клавиатуры и показывает точную дату.

Я пишу стандартно через *.getLocale().getLanguage()* и

```
Date date = new Date();
```

Подскажите, это относится к message resource, или я делаю в корне неверно?

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, имеется ввиду [Resource Bundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). Вы создаете дефолтный файлик с пропертями, где будут хранится все сообщения. Затем вы создаете копии с переводом. При правильной реализации при изменении Locale будут доставаться сообщения для текущего языка.
Кроме того, используйте п[оследнее Date and Time API из Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html)
[Пример использования resource bundle](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-resourcebundle-example/)

Comment: Спасибо. Эх, а у меня все через .txt сделано. Буду исправлять.